# How to install third party library in IDE based on eclipse

Tags: c, windows, eclipse, include, libopencm3

I have downloaded "libopencm3" library for STM32 and IDE SW4STM32 based on eclipse.

I want to add "c:\lib\libopencm3" to libraries which are used in many projects like <stdio.h>.

My IDE during compilation and edition of code doesn't recognize 
 #include <libopencm3/stm32/f4/nvic.h>

Error text during compilation: "Fatal error: libopencm3/stm32/f4/nvic.h: No such file or directory  nvic.h"

What should I do, the Eclipse (SW4STM32) start to recognize the <libopencm3/stm32/f4/nvic.h> as C:/lib/libopencm3/stm32/f4/nvic.h

I work on Windows. I need explanation like for noob (step by step with details) because I start to work with configuration of Eclipse now and I must fastly start to develop applications for STM32F4 processors with third party libraries.